# How to enable a PS file to be globally seen when $profile isn't accessible?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, profile

Usually I put all my scripts in *$PROFILE* file. However, right now I'm at a corporate network and, although the path seems to be set (I can see the path when I type *$profile* in the console), I can't access it (there's path error when I execute *type $profile* or *notepad.exe $profile*).

Optimally, I'd like to be able to access the file like I always do but the client is a rather large corporation with security on pair with Murdoc from Dilbert so I'm certain there's no point talking to the service desk about it.

So, the only other option I've though of is to create a local file (e.g. *c:\scripts\utils.ps*) and edit it to contain all my utilities. The problem is that I have no idea how to make the functions in that file available as runanble commands in the console.

How can I point to a custom file as container of executable commands in PS console?

(Alternative suggestions for an approach are welcome too.)

Comment: If the `$profile` file does not exist, you could create it?

Comment: At its most basic, you can always explicitly dot-source a file: `. .\script.ps1` makes whatever `.\script.ps1` defines available in the current session.

Comment: @Jelphy No, I cant. Saving it to the location specified by *$profile* produces an error saying that the path isn't there. Welcome to big corporate security. :)

Comment: @JeroenMostert I have a single PS file with a bunch of functions. I'd need to call them individually and not execute the whole script file at once. Also, give the path, typing it in defeats the very purpose of convenience. It's still a valid suggestion, that you've made, just not practically helpful. Is there another way?

Comment: "I'd need to call them individually" -- if your script defines, e.g. `function foo {}`, then dot-sourcing it merely makes `foo` available, it doesn't call `foo`. It's the function declaration that gets "executed". This has exactly the same effect as anything you put in the file pointed to by the different profiles. As to not wanting to type the path: after loading it once, you could use a [console file](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/export-console) and create a shortcut to PowerShell that uses `-PSConsoleFile` to load it.

Comment: Are you sure you don’t have access to any of the various profile locations described here: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/05/21/understanding-the-six-powershell-profiles/?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try the following?

- Create the profile file, if possible.

  ```
  New-Item $PROFILE -ItemType File
  ```
- See if you can create any of the other profile files.

  ```
  $PROFILE | gm | ? MemberType -eq "NoteProperty" | % { $PROFILE.($_.Name) }
  ```
- Create a powershell shortcut to..

  ```
  powershell.exe -NoExit -Command ". "C:\Path\To\File.ps1""
  ```

if you're not able to do any of these then you'll need to request your admin grants you some more permissions, you could also add it to your `PATH` and manually run it on startup..

Comment: The first bullet item did the trick. Now let's see if the file I created actually stays where it's supposed to be. In the big-corp world, they sometimes move or even remove the files every now and then. (My VS Code that I installed in an unapproved way disappeared overnight, which was insanely confusing and quite troublesome. NB, There's no approved way around here to install VS Code, by the way.)

Comment: @DonkeyBanana are you using a terminal server or a standalone workstation?

Comment: Not entirely sure where the discriminating line goes. I'm on a laptop (kind of stand alone) but I connect to the bigger network (so technically speaking it's a sort of a terminal). But it's not the type of dumb terminal that only takes input and presents output from the "real" computer, no. May I ask why you wonder about it? The first bullet did indeed resolve the issue and it's been accepted as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your utility scripts into a [module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878340(v=vs.85).aspx) and add the path to a `PSModulePath` environment variable. Any functions exported from your module will be loaded on-the-fly. Not the same as a profile script, but may achieve roughly the same ends.

You may still have to deal with policies that prevent your scripts from running, like execution policy. If you store it on a network drive you may have issues with the path being a trusted location, in which case you want to fully-qualify the UNC paths in your `$PSModulePath` variable.